# When to use Composable vs custom Modifier for side effects?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In jetpack compose, I want to create some reusable side effect, let say lock screen orientation for example. I can create a `@Composable` and put it in whatever view I want.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LockScreenOrientation(orientation: Int) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(orientation) {
        val activity = (context as MainActivity)
        val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
        activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
        onDispose {
            // restore original orientation when view disappears
            activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I can also make it as a `Modifier` and attach it to the view I want.

```kotlin
fun Modifier.lockScreenOrientation(orientation: Int) : Modifier = composed {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(orientation) {
        val activity = (context as MainActivity)
        val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
        activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
        onDispose {
            // restore original orientation when view disappears
            activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
        }
    }
    return@composed this
}
```

My first intuition is that I should avoid using `@Composable` because `LockScreenOrientation` does not add view to the screen, but I realized that `LaunchedEffect`, `DisposableEffect`, `SideEffect` etc. themselves are such examples, so this is not something to avoid.

My question is when should I prefer one approach over the other?

Answer (score 1):

[Modifiers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers) allow you to decorate or augment a composable. Modifiers let you do these sorts of things:

1. Change the composable's size, layout, behavior, and appearance
2. Add information, like accessibility labels
3. Process user input
4. Add high-level interactions, like making an element clickable,
   scrollable, draggable, or zoomable

They are for changing properties of any Composable, with same logic there are also some Scope based Modifiers such as `Modifier.weight` or `Modifier.align/By` in `RowScope` or `ColumnScope`, `Modifier.align` or `Modifier.matchParentSize` in BoxScope so only these specific Composable can use Modifiers. These are Composable specific because they are defined in respective scopes.

The bottom line is they are used for changing general or specific Composable properties.

In your case what effects is not any `Composable` but the `Activity` itself. Attaching your Modifier to any Composable does not effect how they will work and attaching it multiple times that Composables that might enter in a conditional block might also break rotation logic as well.

Also Modifiers can be used to detect recomposition lifecycle(enter recomposition or/and exit recomposiption) of a Composable using `LaunchedEffect` or `DispossableEffect`, for instance when an item is visible to user or removed from `LazyColumn` viewport, but again this Modifier is related to Composable its attached to.